How to handle time-variant observations and slection in selection model?
I'm currently dealing with a selection bias issue using a Heckman two-step model, but I'm facing a challenge with mismatched observation periods between the first and second stages of the model. Typically, the Heckman model assumes that the observation periods for the selection and outcome equations are the same.

However, in my case, these periods do not align as shown in the diagrams below:

First Scenario: Observations for ID A and B span from 2012 to 2014.
Second Scenario: Observations for ID A span from 2012 to 2014, but for ID B they start from 2015 to 2017.
This mismatch raises questions about how to properly calculate the Inverse Mills Ratio (IMR) since the standard Heckman procedure might not directly apply.
My Questions Are:
How can I modify the Heckman model to manage mismatched observation periods in the selection and outcome phases?
Are there alternative econometric methods or models that could be more effective in handling such discrepancies in observation periods?
I appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to approach this issue. Thank you!

Welcome. Your $z_i$ (in the selection equation) is $(z_{i,2012}, z_{i,2013}, z_{i,2014})$. If you have many $i$'s like ID B, you would be able to estimate $\gamma_{2015}, \gamma_{2016}$, and $\gamma_{2017}$ using those observations. I have Wooldridge's model $s_{it} = I(z_i\gamma_t + v_{it}>0)$ in mind, and I assume that whether the outcome is observed in 2012-2014 or 2015-2017 is exogenous.
